# Django submit button is not responding

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to construct a simple webpage that takes in multiple user inputs, then displays them on another page when the user hits submit. Unfortunately my submit button is not responding-when I click on it nothing happens.

Below is the HTML code for the search results:

enter code here

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search results</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% if hashtags.type()==None and user.type()==None and before_date.type()==None and since_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets.</p>
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None and before_date.type()==None and since_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets from user <strong> {{ user }}</strong>.</p> 
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None and user.type()==None and before_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets dated no earlier than <strong>{{ since_date }}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None and user.type()==None and since_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets dated no later than <strong> {{before_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None and before_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets from user <strong> {{user}}</strong> dated no earlier than <strong>{{since_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif user.type()==None and since_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong> {{hashtags}} </strong>dated no later than <strong> {{before_date}} </strong>.</p>
    {% elif since_date.type()==None and before_date.type()==None %}
        <p<You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong> {{hashtags}} </strong> from user <strong>{{user}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None and user.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets dated between<strong> {{since_date}} </strong> and <strong>{{before_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None and since_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets from user<strong> {{user}} </strong> dated no later than <strong>{{before_date}} </strong>.</p>
    {% elif user.type() == None and before_date.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong>{{hashtags}} </strong> dated no earlier than <strong> {{since_date}} </strong>.</p>
    {% elif hashtags.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets from user <strong> {{user}} </strong> dated between <strong>{{since_date}}</strong> and <strong>{{before_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif user.type()==None %}
        <p>You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong>{{hashtags}}</strong> dated between <strong>{{since_date}}</strong> and <strong>{{before_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif since_date.type()==None%}
        <p>You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong>{{hashtags}}</strong> from user <strong>{{user}}</strong> dated no later than <strong>{{before_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% elif before_date.type()==None%}
        <p>You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong> {{hashtags}}</strong> from user <strong>{{user}}</strong> dated no earlier than <strong>{{since_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>You searched for tweets with hashtags <strong> {{hashtags}}</strong> from user <strong>{{user}}</strong> dated between <strong>{{since_date}}</strong> and <strong>{{before_date}}</strong>.</p>
    {%endif %} 
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code for the search form:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search for tweets</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/searched/" method = "post">
        {{form.as_p}}
        {%csrf_token%}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for forms.py

```
from django import forms

class TweetSearchForm(forms.Form):
    hashtags = forms.CharField(required = False, label = "Please enter the hashtags you want to search for.", initial="")
    user = forms.CharField(required = False, label = "Please enter the user whose tweets you want to search.", initial="")
    since_date = forms.CharField(required=False, label = "Please enter the oldest you want your tweets to be.", initial="")
    before_date = forms.CharField(required = False, label = "Please enter the youngest you want your tweets to be."initial="")
```

Here is the views.py:

```
enter code here
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from tweetsearch.forms import *
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
import datetime

def tweet_search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TweetSearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            request.session['cleaneddata']=cd
            #print(cd['hashtags'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/searched/')
    else:
        form = TweetSearchForm()
    return render(request, 'tweet_search_form.html', {'form':form})
def searched(request):
    search_data = request.session.get('cd')
    hashtags = search_data['hashtags']
    user = search_data['user']
    since_date = search_data['since_date']
    before_date = search_data['before_date']

    return render(request, 'tweet_search_result_form.html', {'hashtags':hashtags, 'user':user, 'since_date':since_date, 'before_date':before_date})
```

And finally, please find the urlconf.

```
enter code here
"""tweetsearch URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from tweetsearch.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^tweet_search/$', tweet_search),
    url(r'^searched/$', searched)

]
```

Comment: your form is going to `searched`, I think you need to go to `tweet_search`, since that method is handling the form

Comment: I thought tweet_search was the method handling the search form and searched was handling the result form.

Comment: That is correct, your form's submit should go to `tweet_search`

Comment: So the GET half of the code should handle the initial posting of the code, while the POST half should handle the processing? Would I have to come up with a new form for the post half?

Comment: I will write an answer and try to explain myself better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is submitting to `/searched/` via POST, and in your `urls.py` that pattern is mapped to the `searched` method in `views.py`. So far, so good.

But, in the `searched` method you are not handling that form, nor even the POST method. You can do:

1. Submit the form to the `tweet_search`, since there you handle the form in the POST:

   ```
   <form action="/tweet_search/" method="POST">
   ```
2. Handle the form in `searched`, in the same way you do in `tweet_search`.

Also, your `searched` handler is needless, since it only puts the session's elements in the template rendering engine. You can do that in one handler:

```
def tweet_search(request):
    form = TweetSearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            return render(
                request, 'tweet_search_result_form.html', {'cd': cd}
            )
    return render(
        request, 'tweet_search_form.html', {'form': form}
    )
```

and in `tweet_search_result_form.html` look for the `cd` dictionary:

```
{% if not (cd.hashtags and cd.user and before_date and since_date) %}
    <p>You searched for tweets.</p>
{% endif %}
{# and so on... #}
```

Please note that you don't use parenthesis in Django's default template engine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So would "not cd.hashtags and not cd.user and not cd.before_date and not cd.since_date" work?

Comment: Great! Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my html page and the problem ended up being that I had two

</form>

tags. Submit doesn't work, also, when this html wasn't correct and was duplicated. I didn't see it at first. How I trouble shot was I removed all the html and ran the submit button and it worked. Then I put the html back in one control at a time and I saw the mistake. I hope this helps someone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had the proper `<form>` and `</form>` but because there was a slight error in the HTML, the browser (Firefox) chose to drop the `</form>` tag.  I didn't realize that until I did a view source.  I never would have looked for that if it wasn't for your clue, Marc.

Comment: I don't believe that's it.  I am print the post.data which shows the submit has been invoked.  Yet all the data is the old data.